# Manipulating rasters with QGIS that are stored in PostGIS

Tags: python, postgis, raster, qgis

I am using a QGIS plugin of a friend written in Python, which reclassifies the pixels of a raster by setting points, these points span a polygon and all the pixels within the polygon will be converted or reclassified. So far, it works more or less fine if I use a normal raster image from **my hard disk** in the format of .img or .tiff. By reclassifying the pixels, all the changes will be automatically saved in the image on the disk.

In a next step, I want to store all my raster images in **a PostGIS database** and manipulate them with that tool.  Unfortunately, the tool cannot convert the pixels of the image if I load them into QGIS from the database. 
The tool does not produce any error message. It starts loading and then nothing happens.

**So the question is:** Do I need to adapt the saving method of the plugin or is it generally impossible to manipulate raster images in QGIS which are **stored in a database**, or do I need special rights to access the raster images raster data type?

Comment: You might get some feedback at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Problem is probably with the plugin. But there's not enough info to reach conclusions from what you've mentioned.

Comment: QGIS does not care about the source of a particular dataset. The problem should be with the plugin that assumes data to stem from a file rather than from another source. Usually, tools in QGIS ask you for a target or use a temporary target and add results as a layer to the current project.